How to create short and long versions of gflag flags for command line in CPP?
For example, I'd like to be able to instead of just:
DEFINE_bool(verbose, false, "Run in verbose mode");

which gives me the ability to run ./program --verbose, be able to run --verbose or -v, as well as a number of other different flags with short and long versions. --output -o, --filename -f, etc.
How do I use gflags to do this? (Or is there a different flag system that works significantly better for this use case - I know I've seen gflag do this before, I just can't get it to work now)
Whenever I try to define additional arguments, DEFINE_BOOL takes issue with >3 arguments. I found some solutions for other languages like Python and Rust, but haven't been able to find a method for CPP yet that will allow that.

In the documentation it says this is not supported: Note that flags do not have single-letter synonyms, like they do in the getopt library, nor do we allow "combining" flags behind a single dash, as in ls -la. You may want to look at the library getopt.

I missed that, thank you!
